# How do I reference a named binding in X DI framework from DependencyResolver?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm using Autofac to register multiple concrete types to a single interface using named bindings:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<AlphaProvider>().Named<IProvider>("A");
builder.RegisterType<BetaProvider>().Named<IProvider>("B");

var container = b.Build();

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Now, I need to reference a concrete type by name ("A" or "B"), but can't see a way to do this using the .NET `DependencyResolver`.

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices<IProvider>() //<-- How do I get via name?
```

Is there a way to get the binding by name using the `DependencyResolver`?

Comment: The short answer is NO. You cannot get your named registration from the `DependencyResolver`. And in 95% of the cases you don't need to do that at all. So can you post some more context? In which class do you want to call the `GetServices` and what is the problem what you want to try to solve with it?

Comment: "And in 95% of the cases". I don't agree with @nemesv. The correct wording is "And in 99.5% of the cases" :-)

Comment: "No" answers my question. I've modified my implementation so that it does not require a named binding.